# Getstream.io Import follow relations

Tags: getstream-io

we have video portal where users can follow each other and get updates via email when followed user uploads new video.

We have about 215 756 followers relation in our database.

I tried to run cron on our server to migrated followers to getstream but it takes too long and sometimes it gives connection timeout.

Is there other way to migrate our relations to getstream database. for example upload some json file somewhere or anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getstream-io provides batch import of data in two ways:

### Batch operation

First of you can use batch operations such as [batch follow](http://getstream.io/docs/#batch-follow) and [batch activity add](http://getstream.io/docs/#batch-activity-add). These operations are performed significantly faster than standard follow and add activity operations.

### Import

Second you can send us a data dump (preferred format: json) which we will then import to your app.  Read more about it on this [docs page](http://getstream.io/docs/#import).